# Using UITextField for save file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I use this function to Save a `MyFile.caf`

```
NSString *nomeFile = self.nomeBastard.text;

NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *soundFilePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf", nomeFile]];//@"sound.caf"];
NSString *outputSoundFilePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0.caf", nomeFile]];//@"soundO.caf"];

soundFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
outputSoundFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: outputSoundFilePath];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

my `nomeBastard.text` have a default value (write your name and press REC) but on saved file the value don't change, I svae always one file .caf with the first value like a:

**write your name and press REC.caf**

How can I get the name from my `UITextField`?

Here my screen first I change value on my text filed isert MyFileName

[image]

Whet TAP on Rec the App do not register file with name, but register 0.caf

[image]

Comment: did you try cleaning the project ? @Jhon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to reset the value and set back the placeHolder :

```
self.yourTextField.text = @"";
self.yourTextField.placeHolder = @"write your name and press REC";
```

Apply this code after saving your .caf

And if you want to change the text field with some text :

```
self.yourTextField.text = @"Place Some Text Here";
```

Comment: Not bad thx for the placeholder, but will using the UITextFeild to naming my file .caf and with your method i generate only on file 0.caf becasue take the outputSoundFilePath

Comment: i really don't understand why if i edit textfield my NSStRing don't take the new value

Comment: I don't really understand what you want... Could you add picture or more explanation please ? I will answer you soon after that :)

Comment: Update my screen, i want olny insert a name in to UITextField and get same name in both NSString (soundFilePath and outputSoundFilePath)

Comment: `NSString *nomeFile = self.nomeBastard.text;` should get the name of your textField if, when you click on the button you get the text of this textField